# Rails and HTML: How do i keep the formatting of a forms input

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Hi I have a rails app with a simple HTML form. One of the fields called `description` is a `text_area` and I want to be able to display its input exactly how is was entered on the index page.

For example:

If someone enters input into the text area as a list. I want it to display exactly like that.

**Sample description input**

```
-list1
-list2
-list3
```

When I submit the form with this input, the following string is stored as the `description` field `"-list1\r\n-list2\r\n-list3"`. And when I output `description` like so:

```
<div class='light panel radius bottom'>
  <%= job.description %>
</div>
```

This is the output:

```
-list1 -list2 -list3
```

I know if I wanted I could just parse the `\r\n` and replace it with a `<br>`. But that seems like a really ridiculous solution to something that should be easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you do need to use HTML tags to create line breaks, because browsers do not respond to `"\n"`. HTML layout rendering looks at HTML tags, not text content.

Comment: Yep, you want simple_format (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format)